# Possible to have Facebook review a concept before building it?

Tags: facebook, review

We're building a piece of functionality that will require approval for users to mention friends in posts from our app.

It's quite a complex piece of development and we're not 100% sure if Facebook will approve it, so rather than spend ages coding it only for it to be rejected by Facebook we're looking for a 'leaner' approach and wondered, is it possible to describe our concept and the action in question (in slides and description paragraph) to see if they approve it in principle first? Then obviously we'd have to build the full version of it for them to approve it for use.

Anybody got any experience of this?

Answer (score 1):

First, describe your features in the official Facebook Developers group: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

If you don´t get any good answer, you may need to create a prototype with basic functionality. Design implementation is irrelevant, just create the part that´s relevant for review and explain what you want to do with videos and screenshots. It must be functional though.

Comment: Thanks very much for this luschn. So Facebook are happy to receive  prototypes of that kind for review purposes? They don't need to see the designs or other elements of the site?

Comment: yeah, it does not have to be completely finished.